# You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Есть следующая структура:

```
 src/index:
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );

  App.js:
   <main className={ styles.main }>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Main}/>
      <Route path='/products' component={ProductsConteiner}/>
    </Switch>
   </main>


   ....
    export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps,  mapDispatchToProps, null, {pure: false}),
    withRouter
      )(ProductsConteiner);
```

Почему когда я оборачиваю ProductsConteiner в WithRouter , то возникает подобная ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге проблема была решена установкой более ранней версии react-router

Answer (score 0):

Хотел написать комментарий, но слишком много получается текста, поэтому дам ответ, который будет полезен. Для полноты ясности, по-хорошему, нужно было привести код `ProductsConteiner` компонента в вашем вопросе, но его нет. Судя по экспорту, видимо обертки сделаны не совсем корректно.

В вашем конкретном случае вам не нужно использовать `compose`, используйте его по мере добавления HOC. Я думаю, что лучше использовать `compose`, когда у вас более двух HOC-ов, в противном случае это просто дополнительный слой, который может добавить ошибку и сложность в понимании кода.

Перейдем к обертке в HOC-и, я бы рекомендовал упростить ваш код и писать так (добавил переносы для удобности чтения):

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
  null,
  {pure: false}
)(withRouter(ProductsConteiner));
```

Ну а вообще, можно предложить вариант с `compose` вот такой:

```
export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, {pure: false})(ProductsConteiner)
);
```

Или вот такой:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, {pure: false})(compose(
  withRouter,
  ProductsConteiner
));
```

Ну а судя по ошибке, видимо у вас строится DOM не совсем корректный и получается так, что `<Route>` находится за пределами `<Router>`, хотя должен находиться внутри него. Также, считаю, что будет полезной следующая ссылка: [Higher-Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)